# How to check if a package is enabled via shell?

Tags: applications, adb, tasker, shell, disable-app

I have been writing a tasker task to enable/disable a package. I know

`adb shell pm enable com.android.contacts`

will enable the package and

`adb shell pm disable com.android.contacts`

will disable it.

I would like to know if there's any shell command that would tell me if a package is in enabled/disabled state. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
pm list packages -d 2>/dev/null
```

will list up all disabled packages, one per line, preceded with the keyword `package:` – so output looks like

```
package:com.android.exchange
package:com.android.email
```

So if you take that output and "grep" it for the package name in question, the package is enabled if the output is "empty" and disabled otherwise. Alternatively, if you want a number (0/1), you can use the `wc` utility:

```
pm list packages -d 2>/dev/null | grep com.android.exchange | wc -l
```

would return "1" in above example, meaning the package `com.android.exchange` is disabled. It would, however, return "0" if I'd grep for `com.foobar.app` – which doesn't necessarily mean that `com.foobar.app` is enabled but could also mean it's simply not installed :) So if you want to cross-check, you can do so running the same command with `pm list packages -e` (to list enabled packages).

Answer (score 2):

There are apps that have similar names, so just a simple grep might be problematic. Take the following apps for instance.

```
com.amazon.dcp
com.amazon.dcp.contracts.framework.library
```

If the short one is enabled and the long one is disabled, you will get a result searching the list of disabled apps.
Here is a function to determine if an app is disabled.

```
check_apk_disabled(){ # Check if a package is disabled. Return 1 if installed else 0
            [ $# -lt 1 ] && return 2
            adb shell pm list packages -d | cut -d: -f2 | sed 's|\r||' | grep -c "^${1}$"; }
```

The package list is stripped of `package:` as well as the `0D` byte. Grep can then find an exact match with ^ at start and $ at the end.

`check_apk_disabled com.android.contacts` will return `1` if disabled or `0` if not. It should be noted that if an app is not installed then it will not appear on the disabled list and trying to disable an app that is not installed will generate errors. A check if the app is installed should be done before assuming it is not disabled.

```
check_apk_installed(){ # Check if a package is installed. Return 1 if installed else 0
            [ $# -lt 1 ] && return 2
            adb shell pm list packages | cut -d: -f2 | sed 's|\r||' | grep -c "^${1}$"; }
```

Now with these 2 functions you can disable the app properly.

```
apk=com.android.contacts
[ $(check_apk_installed $apk) == "1" ] && [ $(check_apk_disabled $apk) == "0" ] && adb pm disable-user --user=0 $apk 2>/dev/null || echo "app is not installed or already disabled"
```

Sorry to necro the post, but the potential to disable the wrong app in the original answer scared me!